# JS stop current Audio object of playing load new one

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am creating a Podcast app using Ionic and AngularJS

I have two views:

- List View (displaying all podcasts)
- Detailed View (selected podcast)

[image: List View]

Every time the user opens detailed view I grab the new podcast URL from the database and I load it in a new Audio object.

```
sound = new Audio($scope.mp3);
```

If I play a podcast and then go back on the list view and select another podcast and play it, the currently playing one doesen't stop and then I have two (or many) playing at the same time.

[image: Detailed View]

```js
angular.module('starter.controllers', ['firebase'])


.controller('AppCtrl', function($scope, $ionicModal, $timeout) {

   // Initialize Firebase


  // With the new view caching in Ionic, Controllers are only called
  // when they are recreated or on app start, instead of every page change.
  // To listen for when this page is active (for example, to refresh data),
  // listen for the $ionicView.enter event:
  //$scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(e) {
  //});

  // Form data for the login modal
  $scope.loginData = {};

  // Create the login modal that we will use later
  $ionicModal.fromTemplateUrl('templates/login.html', {
    scope: $scope
  }).then(function(modal) {
    $scope.modal = modal;
  });

  // Triggered in the login modal to close it
  $scope.closeLogin = function() {
    $scope.modal.hide();
  };

  // Open the login modal
  $scope.login = function() {
    $scope.modal.show();
  };

  // Perform the login action when the user submits the login form
  $scope.doLogin = function() {
    console.log('Doing login', $scope.loginData);

    // Simulate a login delay. Remove this and replace with your login
    // code if using a login system
    $timeout(function() {
      $scope.closeLogin();
    }, 1000);
  };

})

// Browse Controller
.controller('BrowseCtrl', function($scope, $http, $firebaseArray) {
  // Create Podcast reference 
  const dbRefObject = firebase.database().ref().child('podcasts');
  $scope.playlists = $firebaseArray(dbRefObject);
  console.log($firebaseArray(dbRefObject));
})




// Podcast Detailed Controller
.controller('PodcastCtrlDetailed', function($scope, $http, $stateParams, $firebaseArray) {

  // URL Parameter
  var podcastRefID = $stateParams.playlistId;

  const oneRef = firebase.database().ref().child('podcasts').child(podcastRefID).on("value", function(snapshot) {

    $scope.mp3 = snapshot.val().audio;
    sound = new Audio($scope.mp3);

    $scope.playSong = function() {
      
      if (sound.duration > 0 && !sound.paused) {
        sound.pause();
      } else {
          sound.play();
      }

    }; 


  }, function (errorObject) {
    console.log("The read failed: " + errorObject.code);
  });


});
```

And this is how I initalise the Play and Pause

```
<i class="ion-play" ng-click="playSong()" ></i>
```

Is there any way of making the currently playing podcast stop and start the newly selected one?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you post the rest of your code? My guess is that the fix is in having the dedicated audio element live outside of the context of your other views. With *one* `audio` element tasked with playing  mp3, simply updating the `src` of that element would ensure only one sound is playing.

Comment: I've added the full code now. I think that new Audio keeps creating new objects instead of replacing them like if it was a variable. Hmm...

Comment: Have you tried var sound = new Audio($scope.mp3); ?

Comment: That was the original code. I don't know why I've taken it off but yeah the problem is still there

Comment: Use a service to play the song. You will have a sigle instance of you sound var.
I assume, in your code, each time you click on another podcast you will not reload the currently PodcastCtrlDetailed controller, but create a new one.

Comment: Checkout the cordovaNativeAudio plugin, it will do all the work for you

Comment: Okay I will have a look at using a service. I don't want to be using cordova at this point as I want the app to run on the web too.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a new `New Audio($scope.mp3)` is created for each podcast reference (...`.child('podcasts').child(podcastRefID)`...).

Try having a single shared Audio reference by declaring it in a higher scope, alongside `var podcastRefID = $stateParams.playlistId`

This single instance is the way you want to pause, and update the `src` when the selected podcast changes